# How to move the bones of a model by just pressing a key in unreal engine 5?

Tags: skeletal-animation, unreal-5

I have the following problem. I need to be able to rotate a bone (any bone) in a model in unreal engine 5.3. I cannot use the timeline. For example, if I press the space bar then I would need the arm to rotate. I cannot find a way to do it. Any recommendations?